# Why $(U+iI_n)^2 = (U+iI_n)(U^*-iI_n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U$, a unitary operator and let $U+iI_n$, self-conjugate operator.

Why is it true that:

$$(U+iI_n)^2 = (U+iI_n)(U^*-iI_n)$$

We can evaluate both sides of the equation to get:
$$(U+iI_n)^2 = U^2 + 2iU -I_n \\ (U+iI_n)(U^*-iI_n) = 2I_n + iU^*-iU$$

but how can I conclude the equality?

Comment: What do you mean by self-conjugate? Do you mean self-adjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not much to do here if $U+iI$ is assumed to be self-conjugate - it is just the definition. Self-conjugate means that $A=A^*=\bar{A}^T$ (Hermitian or [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)), so we have
$$
U+iI=(U+iI)^*=U^*+(iI)^*=U^*-iI,
$$
which gives
$$
(U+iI)^2=(U+iI)(U+iI)=(U+iI)(U+iI)^*=(U+iI)(U^*-iI).
$$